# Playing m4a/ALAC files in Appcelerator generated iOS Application

Tags: ios, audio, appcelerator, mp4, m4a

I am developing an audio player iOS app, and I am currently interested to play m4a (ALAC) audio. I can play this audio using the VideoPlayer object.

However using the AudioPlayer object -which makes more sense to me- silently fails to play the file. Since ALAC/m4a is natively supported I'm expecting to be able to use the AudioPlayer. I would love to know if I just cannot use the AudioPlayer for this purpose, or if it could be another reason it will not play.

```
audio_streamer = Titanium.Media.createAudioPlayer({
    allowBackground: true,
    allowsAirPlay:true,
    url:'http://cdn.challenge.nl/transcoding/test.m4a'
});


audio_streamer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and, yes, no audio streaming occurs with the m4a file in the url of your snippet, in an iOS app (but it is playing when accessed in OS X Safari); then I tested it with a different source file (m4a, ALAC) and found it working:

```
var audio_streamer = Titanium.Media.createAudioPlayer({
    allowBackground: true,
    allowsAirPlay:true,
    url: "http://www.hyperion-records.co.uk/audiotest/18%20MacCunn%20The%20Lay%20of%20the%20Last%20Minstrel%20-%20Part%202%20Final%20chorus%20O%20Caledonia!%20stern%20and%20wild.M4A"
});

audio_streamer.start();
```

I understand this is not a solution answer, but maybe could be a clue. Hth.

Comment: Thanks, i will compare the files and see what causes the issue.